# Not able to successfully add Google Analytics Event Tag to link created by .attr

Tags: jquery, onclick, google-analytics, bind

I am working with jQuery code created by someone else, and I am very new to jQuery (fair warning).

I need to add google event tags to the links the jQuery is creating.   This jQuery is for a modal pop up that contains icons for various sizes of an item, and a static button.  When the user hovers over the icon, the link on the button changes, and I need to add google analytics tagging to the link for each icon when it changes on the button.

Here is the code that creates the link for the button when a particular icon is hovered over:

```
$('#modal_sizes_4 .size_5').hover(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $('#modal_sizes_4 .selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#modal_sizes_4 .detail_left h3').text('15 3/4” Item');
        $('#modal_sizes_4 .detail_left p').text('Good for many things.');
        $('#modal_sizes_4 .detail_right img').attr({
            src: 'images/5.4.5-product.jpg'
        });
        $('#modal_sizes_4 .detail_bottom a.shop_size').attr({
            href: 'http://testing.com'
        });
    }
});
```

​
What is the best way to add this to the link once it's created:

```
onclick = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','CIGuide', 'Click Shop Size', '15 3/4 Item']);" >​
```

I have tried using .click, .attr, .on and .bind with no luck.

I apologize if my question doesn't make perfect sense, again, I am very new to all of this.
Any help would be appreciated. What I am ultimately trying to achieve is an event tag in google. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to add the call:

```
$( "#my_element a" ).bind( "mousedown" , function() {
    _gaq.push( [ "_trackEvent" , "CIGuide" , "Click Shop Size" , "15 3/4 Item" ] ) ;
} ) ;
```

The code above will work for any anchor under the element whose id is "my_element":

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div id="my_element">
    <h2>Title here</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./some-page.html">Some Page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.anotherexample.com">Another Example</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="./wont-fire">This link won't fire the event</a>
```

Customize the selector to fit your purposes and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this still didn't work for me - I think your code is correct but there is a problem with my CMS or server or something...can't quite figure it out.  Going to post a new question. Thank you.