# Adding any additional JavaScript is breaking functionality within jQuery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have a page created by someone else that contains modal windows, and each modal window has links/images that display on hover.  FYI, I have a very limited understanding of JavaScript and jQuery.

What I am trying to achieve is to add Google Analytics event tags to the links in the modal windows. It would work with onclick (code below) added directly to the anchor tag, or if it is added to the link via jQuery/JavaScript).  The event needs to fire as a click event in Google Anayltics.

Usually, I just add:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Parameter 1', 'Parameter 2', 'Parameter 3']);"
```

directly to the anchor tag, but whenever I add the code to the anchor tag in the HTML, the jQuery stops working.  The modal windows work correctly on this link:
http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_cast-iron-guide-sizes_10151_-1_20002

and you can see what I mean by "stops working" on the following link - the items within the list tags are no longer being populated, which means the icons don't show up and the new content that displays on hover can't be accessed: http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_test-form_10151_-1_20002

Since most of the links are created in the jQuery, I started by trying to add the Google Tag via .click, .attr, .on and .bind with no luck.  The link above shows you my attempt with the .click function (search for CIGuide and you'll find it in the source on the 2nd link), but it breaks in the same way no matter what JavaScript I add to the page. My original question is here: [Not able to successfully add Google Analytics Event Tag to link created by .attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844292/not-able-to-successfully-add-google-analytics-event-tag-to-link-created-by-attr)

After I wasn't able to get either of those two things to work, I decided to try a simple alert on the page outside of all the content I was provided, with it's own JavaScript tags, just to see if I could get that to work.  It worked perfectly, but the modal functionality still broke.

I have been able to successfully add the Google Tags to the anchor in the top navigation, and to the arrows on the left and right side of the page.  But anytime I try to tag anything else, it breaks.

The agency I'm working with is able to add the google tag to the anchor with no issue when they test it on their server, and I am able to see the event fire if I test it on my local machine.  I have to assume there is a problem on my server or with OpenCMS. However, I don't see any error messages in any browser/debugger, and I have validated my script additions with JSLint, and everything checks out.

This is driving me nuts! Can anyone help me figure out why this won't work and how I can add event tags to the page?

Comment: so if i manage to invoke an `alert` and the hover functionality still works, you'd be happy right?

Comment: If your being able to do that would help me answer why it's breaking when anything is added to the page, then yes sir.

Comment: I also tried changing the _gaq.push call to console.log just to see if it would still break, and it does.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, and if it would work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#modal_sizes_1 a").each(function( index, elem ) {

        $(elem).click(function() {

            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Parameter 1', 'Parameter 2', 'Parameter 3']);
        });
    });
});
```

**Update**
Okay, so I think it's about this line:

```
<a
    href="/cookware/content_cast-iron-guide-about_10151_-1_20002"
    title="About Cast Iron" 
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','CIGuide', 'Click', 'About Cast Iron']);"

>About Cast Iron</a>
```

And I would try to change it like this

```
<a
    href="/cookware/content_cast-iron-guide-about_10151_-1_20002"
    title="About Cast Iron" 
    onclick="setTimeout(function(){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','CIGuide', 'Click', 'About Cast Iron']);
    },0);"

>About Cast Iron</a>
```

Or even make the delay longer than `0`, like 10 or 50.

Comment: I'm trying to add the _gaq push call to the link, but any time I add any additional script to the page the content in the modal window stops working, whether I add it within the existing functions or within their own script tags. I will update my question to clarify what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. I couldnt find 'CIGuide' as you suggested to search for.

Comment: Did you look in the 2nd URL? It should be there: http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_test-form_10151_-1_20002

Comment: My bad, the line was so long, its probably somewhere in the end. Lack of formatting, expected JS not html lol.

Comment: I know, the formatting breaks at some point between my pasting into the CMS and the processing  of it...sorry about that. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: So maybe the click event does an `event.stopPropagation()`. This means that after processing the click event, no other events will occur anymore. Then you should should use a `setTimeout` for the blocking onclick.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21415/discussion-between-ericg-and-surfbird0713)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback for the GA push method and add the timeout. In your case try something like this:

```
var submitBtn = $('.submit-btn');

submitBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    var that = this;

    if (typeof _gaq != 'undefined') {
        e.preventDefault();

        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Parameter 1', 'Parameter 2', 'Parameter 3'], function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = $(that).attr('href');
            }, 100);
        });
    }
});
```